# Is there a port of the linux ip command to Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, ipconfig, replacement

I am constantly switching between MS Windows and Linux and would love to use the Linux `ip` command on Windows instead of `ipconfig` or `route`.

I tried to locate a port of `ip` to Linux but the unfortunate name (from a search perspective) makes it impossible for me to check that (on top of that "port" is understood as a TCP port and I get plenty of suggestion on how to fix or understand tcp/ip on Windows or Linux...)

Does such a port exist?

Comment: Have you tried instead searching for "iproute2", the actual name of the project that provides /bin/ip?

Comment: @user1686: very good idea, thank you. It unfortunately seems that there is no such port.

Comment: I think you'll have to make do with `ipconfig` and PowerShell [Get-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=windowsserver2022-ps). WSL will have the `ip` command, but might be too remote from the real hardware (except if using WSL1).